# c++ friend function of template with two parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

Let I have such `class Foo` and its friend function `::f`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename U>
    friend inline void f(Foo<T>, Foo<U>) {}     
};
```

Then I call it like this `f(Foo<double>(), Foo<int>())`,
friend of who will be `::f`?

Only `Foo<double>` or it will
be friend of `Foo<int>` also, I mean `::f` become friend for `Foo<T>` for any `T` at the time of declaration, or at the time of usage compiler generate `::f`
for `T=double` and find out that it is friend of `Foo<double>` and not friend of `Foo<int>`?

And if I declare `::f` like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename U1, typename U2>
    friend inline void f(Foo<U1>, Foo<U2>) {}
};
```

Again friend of who become `::f` after call `f(Foo<double>(), Foo<int>());`

**Note**: the second variant compiled only by clang, not gcc.

**Note** it would be great to see answers with reference to standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a single function template - you have an unbounded family of them. With each instantiation `Foo<X>`, a new function template is defined,

```
template <typename U>
void f(Foo<X>, Foo<U>) {}
```

All instantiations of this template are friends of `Foo<X>` (but not of any `Foo<U>` for `U != X`).

Thus, when you write `f(Foo<double>(), Foo<int>())`, `Foo<double>` and `Foo<int>` are instantiated, and with them, two overloads of `f` are defined:

```
template <typename U>
void f(Foo<double>, Foo<U>) {}

template <typename U>
void f(Foo<int>, Foo<U>) {}
```

Overload resolution selects the first one for the call (the second is not viable), which is instantiated for `U==int`. This instantiation, `f<int>(Foo<double>, Foo<int>)`, is a friend of `Foo<double>` but not `Foo<int>`.

---

In your second example, I believe gcc is right in rejecting the code, and clang is wrong in accepting it (for what it's worth, MSVC agrees with gcc). Every instantiation of `Foo<X>` introduces a definition of the same template into the enclosing scope:

```
template <typename U1, typename U2>
void f(Foo<U1>, Foo<U2>) {}
```

When a translation unit performs two instantiaions of `Foo`, it ends up with two identical definitions of `f`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer